# Docker: disable caching for a specific stage

Tags: docker

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile. In stage one, I `git clone` from a github repo. In later stage, I do other stuff like `pip` etc and use a file from stage 1. I'd like to only disable caching for the first stage.

It looks like `docker build --target stage1 --no-cache` doesn't do what I want.

Is there a way to disable only a certain stage?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM yijian/git-alpine
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN git clone https://github.com/abc/abc.git


FROM python:3.5.3-slim

RUN mkdir /app
ADD requirements.txt /app
ADD pip/pip.conf /root/.pip/pip.conf
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install pbr && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD server.py /app
ADD docker/start.sh /app
RUN chmod a+x /app/start.sh
COPY --from=0 /tmp/abc/directory /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/abc/directory


EXPOSE 9092
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you show your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: added to question

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34715 was almost what you wanted. But not quite.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that a single Dockerfile can have caching disabled for a specific state.  That might make a nice feature request but I would rather see that as a declarative statement in the file rather than on the command line.

According to Docker's reference site:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#usage

The "--target" flag allows you to select a target stage from a Dockerfile, meaning that it would only run that part of the Dockerfile.  I would expect that the --no-cache flag would work in conjunction with this flag, however I wouldn't expect the other sections of the Dockerfile to run.

I believe that what you want to occur would take multiple commands which may defeat the purpose of having a multistage Dockerfile.

It would take more work, but depending on what you want to cache, you could possible include a script, such as bash or powershell, which can accomplish this goal.

Another option (depending on your needs) may be to use a separate Docker container which caches just what you need.  For instance, I created a CI build which uses a Dockerfile that only imports dependencies and then my main build happens in a container that references that first container.  I have done this with "dotnet restore" commands, so that the dependencies are preloaded and also have done this using "npm install".  This method would work with any package management tool which allows you to specify a source.  so where you have a project.json, you can extract the common dependencies and call it cache.package.json, then build a base image that has already done the heavy downloading for you, then ideally when you run this again during your more frequent builds it needs to pull less.  Take advantage of the layered approach Docker offers!

Answer (score 0):

If your earlier stages change more often than the later ones you might want to consider reversing the order of the stages.

Stage 1. Setup your environment with pip (possibly in an virtual env).
Stage 2. copy environment files for virtual env from previous stage & then do git clone.

As long as your stage 1 doesn't need to change the cache can be used there and only the git clone part will be updated.

Comment: Sometimes this is not applicable for security. Assume stages `builder` and `production`. One case in which you should not reverse the order, for example, is if stage `builder` which is making the "git clone" does have an SSH private key injected via ARG that we do not want to keep in the "set layers" of the `production` image. Then you first do the `builder` to make the clones. Then after that you do the `production` image and at some point you copy the cloned dirs but not all the filesystem. This way the SSH keys are not present at **any** layer of `production`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Sure this is probably not always applicable but in the described case in the question you could divide it in three stages - 1. `clone` where you do git clone, 2. `build` where you create your venv folder with pip install, 3. `production` where you copy the cloned files from the first stage and the venv folder from the second stage and nothing else is left in the production stage. Or something of that sort. In any case I'm no suggesting that my answer is universally applicable.